# to import and use data in multiple worksheets of excel workbook, one by one in R

Tags: r

I am working on trading data and generated output in an excel workbook d://ranks.xls with 217 worksheets, each worksheet contains 125 columns and 338 rows. Now want to use each worksheet data as input so, using

```
library(gdata)  
   for (i in 1:217)  
   {    
   dat[[i]]<-read.xls("d://ranks.xls",sheet=i,head=F)  
   }
```

its making a list rather i just want to call and use each sheet one by one... its toooooo much time consuming also ... is there any other way to do the same quickly????